Using Allotted in a Sentence
In the following sentence, is the word allotted used correctly?

Unless I reschedule in the allotted 24 hour time frame given then I will need to keep my appointment.


Please use caps for the pronoun I. Also, correction (editing) is not what we do here. Please read the Help section at the top right of your screen under the last icon. Thanks.

We don't usually include preposition in when we schedule a meeting, and we'd almost never include it when rescheduling.

@FumbleFingers don't usually include a/the preposition in? when we schedule a meeting.

@Lambie: Relevant usage chart.

@FumbleFingers I'm saying you need an a or the in front of the word preposition.

'I' is always a capital letter, and 'allotted' has two t's.

@Lambie: Of course I don't need an article there! Not in my version of English, anyway. Would you like it any better if I put in in "scare quotes"? Some of the dozens of examples in that link do, but they don't have the benefit of easy highlighting!

Anyway, I think this question can't be properly answered unless and unti the OP explains exactly what the purpose of including the word allotted is. If what needed to be rescheduled was an appointment rather than a 24 hour time frame, I don't think anyone would include either of the bracketed elements in Unless I reschedule the [allotted] appointment [given] I will need to take time off work on that day.

We don't usually include the preposition in when we schedule a meeting.

You're just repeating yourself. Are you seriously claiming that all the published writers in my link are incompetent?

Rephrased: "Unless I reschedule within the allotted 24-hour timeframe, I will have to keep my (current) appointment (time)." The word "given" in the original is redundant with "allotted," and "then" is ungrammatical after the "unless" clause. Adding the words current and time makes the result of missing the 24-hour window more clear: you will no longer be able to change the timeslot for the appointment.

Your sentence has a number of issues, but the answer to your question is "kind of, but not really."
If you really want to use allotted, you would probably use it to describe the time period when you could cancel your appointment, not when you couldn't. For example:

They have allotted 30 days as a cancellation period.

meaning you have 30 days to cancel.
Some form of allow is a better choice, and it can be used to describe both periods. For example:

You're only allowed to cancel up to 24 hours before your appointment starts.
You're not allowed to cancel within 24 hours.

But there are many different ways to express this:

If I don't cancel 24 hours in advance, I have to keep my appointment.
I can cancel up to 24 hours in advance without a penalty.

